# How to automate challenge-response authentication using Java

Tags: java, ssh, automation, jsch, challenge-response

I have Linux phone with enabled SSH. I need to connect to it via challenge-response authentication. So how looks this process manually, for example, using PuTTY:

1. Connect to phone using IP and port.
2. Console shows "login as:" -> Enter user name.
3. Console shows:

   > login as: craft
   >
   > Challenge: 547-04302
   >   Product ID: 7000315107
   >
   > Response:
4. I need to copy Challenge, get Response from other server using Challenge and enter the Response in console.

How I can do this using Java and some libraries for SSH (I tried JSch, but there are no methods for challenge-response)? I need only to write Challenge into String, and after that enter the Response using String response.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge-response authentication is also known as a keyboard-interactive authentication.

And it is supported by the JSch library.

See the official [JSch `UserAuthKI` example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/UserAuthKI.java.html).

Basically you need to implement the [`UIKeyboardInteractive` interface](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/UIKeyboardInteractive.html) (together with the [`UserInfo` interface](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/UserInfo.html)) and associate the implementation with the session using the [`Session.setUserInfo`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html#setUserInfo-com.jcraft.jsch.UserInfo-).

To use a programmatic response to a single challenge, just collect the challenge from the `prompt[0]` parameter of the [`UIKeyboardInteractive.promptKeyboardInteractive` method](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/UIKeyboardInteractive.html#promptKeyboardInteractive-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-boolean:A-) and return a single element array with the response.

Comment: I rewrited UserAuthKeyboardInteractive class according to my example (added code to parse `String[] response=new String[prompt.length];` from `promptKeyboardInteractive` method and methods for getting response using Challenge via Selenium) , all works. Your comment was helpful for me, Thanks